# UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal

Tags: cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller

When using the above, it scrolls the new view vertically up the screen, and dismisses it by scrolling the view down the screen. Why is this, and how do I overcome this? (Especially since it should be a horizontal animation)

My code is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)infoButtonPressed:(id)sender {
InfoViewController *infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"DAandPAInfo" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];
self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController: infoViewController animated: YES];
[infoViewController release];
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I realised my mistake.

```
infoViewController.modalTransitionStyle = ...
```